# Apple Configurator 2: Apply Blueprint one by one

Tags: macos, mobile-device-management, apple-configurator

I have 48 iPads here and if I apply a blueprint to all of them at once, the network to the MDM server is jammed. If I apply the blueprint one by one to each iPad, every thing goes smoothly.

Is there a way to tell Configurator to apply a blueprint one by one?

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine MDM network getting jammed. What's the MDM you use and how is it configured? (i.e. what data needs to transfer for you blueprint of choice?)

Comment: I just make an automated enrollment and push 3 apps.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty lightweight. I use Caching server so that the first iOS device to download the three apps gets it from Apple, but then all the rest of the iOS devices get it from the local cache. That might help with your network.

Answer (score 1):

No, not with Version 2.1 (3B42) of Apple Configurator. There are some workarounds that come to mind:

- You could make smaller groups and keep the same blueprints
- You could determine the limiting factor in your MDM responsiveness and address that to handle 50 devices at once.
- You could re-implement the blueprint in a script and have that script iterate over the group with delays that resolve the bottleneck.

It really depends on what you are doing. If you cannot add a simple blueprint that adds one Web Clip to all 48 devices, then you might need to rethink your MDM or infrastructure. I'm having a hard time imagining something that saturates a link to MDM since they generally are quite efficient and just transfer configuration data and not loads of document data.

Comment: How could I determine the "limiting factor" in my MDM. Actually, I saw some message in some log of the MDM (ProfileManager), that not all clients could be served, because there are too many. Unfortunately, I don't remember any name. I just remember, that some PHP variable should be adapted. Can you tell me which variable or how to do it?

Comment: The problem with the script is, that I have to re-implement the blueprint, which is a pity. But that's probably, what I will do, if the limiting factor of the MDM doesn't help.

Comment: @Heiri Yup. I've sent feedback to Apple to allow the command line tool to read blueprints. If you want that considered or coded, you might submit a request to your contact and explain how many devices it impacts. If enough people want that feature, it surely could be coded for some future release.

Comment: I also made a feature enhancement.

Comment: Please, does anybody have an idea, where I could find those configuration variables for ProfileManager? Especially the ones to allow more clients?